# How to draw a simple rectangle on DrawingArea with specific size, and X Y positions?

Tags: c#, mono, draw, gtk#

How can I draw a rectangle on a drawingarea in Mono, GTK#?? I dont want to draw it using the mouse. Thus, I want to do the following but I do not know the right syntax:

```
int X = 10;
int Y = 10;
int SizeW = 10;
int SizeH = 10;

Drawingarea.DrawRectangle(x,y, SizeW, SizeH);
```

Comment: Just a note: you don't need to prepend GTK#, MONO to your question. Use tags for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Step 1. Create an eventbox and change the size of the eventbox. 
Step 2. Add an imagewidget (without an image) inside the eventbox. 
Step 3. Decide on a color or add a Colorbutton to determinecolor. 
Step 4. Create a function as the following:

```
 Private void DrawRectangle()
    {
    Gdk.Color RectangleColor = colorbutton_RectangleColor.Color;
    eventbox_rectangle.ModifyBg(StateType.Normal, RectangleColor); 
    //To modify the size of the rectangle use the following.
    eventbox_rectangle.HeightRequest = 10;
    eventbox_rectangle.WidthRequest = 10;
    }
```

Comment: Would recommend to put the Eventbox inside a Fixed-Container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only posting, because I am super annoyed that there are no answers in StackOverflow for such specific questions. The answer above doesn't answer the initial question in any way :D

```
gc.RgbFgColor = new Gdk.Color(204,204,204);
```

You need to change the Gdk.GC Object you're using.